# How to enlarge the 'click-zone' around a form element?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I'm looking to enlarge the clickable zone around my radio buttons.

This is what I have:

[image: have]

This is what I want:

[image: want]

I tried the following ([jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2bLtD/9/)), but `width` and `height` attributes don't seem to be working on `<label>`...

**HTML**:

```
<div style="white-space:nowrap;">
    <span class="radio_option">
        <input type="radio" id="one" name="click_item" value="1" />
        <label class="radio_label" for="one">First Item</label>
    </span>
    <span class="radio_option">
        <input type="radio" id="two" name="click_item" value="2" />
        <label class="radio_label" for="two">Second Item</label>
    </span>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
span.radio_option {
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
span.radio_option:hover {
    background: #E0E0E0;
}
label.radio_label {
   width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
}
label.radio_label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u have to add

```
display: inline-block
```

and width to label.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2bLtD/17/

CSS:

```
label{
    display: inline-block;   
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tweaked your code a bit, and got it working exactly the way I wanted it. Here's the final: http://jsfiddle.net/2bLtD/24/

Answer (score 3):

**Updated:** Add padding to your `span.radio_option`. Add `display:inline-block` and set a width.

```
span.radio_option {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display:inline-block; 
    width:120px;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2bLtD/15/

Comment: Got it! But why won't `width` and `height` work on `<label>`? I even tried adding `display:block`, but to no use.. o_O

Comment: Oh, and there's a problem with your approach. The two zones are not of the same width (which I wanted)! Also, `width` and `height` doesn't seem to be working on `span.radio_option` either.. :(

Comment: display:inline-block; then you can define a width and height.

Comment: Still not perfect. With http://jsfiddle.net/2bLtD/15/, clicking inside the box where there's no text has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `padding: 5px 10px;` to `span.radio_option` achieves the desired effect. Change the values to your needs.

Here's a [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/friiks/2bLtD/11/) with the code.